# MatchError when match receives an IndexedSeq but not a LinearSeq

Tags: scala, match, seq

Is there a reason that `match` written against `Seq` would work differently on `IndexedSeq` types than the way it does on `LinearSeq` types?  To me it seems like the code below should do the exact same thing regardless of the input types. Of course it doesn't or I wouldn't be asking.

```
import collection.immutable.LinearSeq
object vectorMatch {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    doIt(Seq(1,2,3,4,7), Seq(1,4,6,9))
    doIt(List(1,2,3,4,7), List(1,4,6,9))
    doIt(LinearSeq(1,2,3,4,7), LinearSeq(1,4,6,9))
    doIt(IndexedSeq(1,2,3,4,7), IndexedSeq(1,4,6,9))
    doIt(Vector(1,2,3,4,7), Vector(1,4,6,9))
  }

  def doIt(a: Seq[Long], b: Seq[Long]) {
    try {
      println("OK! " + m(a, b))
    }
    catch {
      case ex: Exception => println("m(%s, %s) failed with %s".format(a, b, ex))
    }
  }

  @annotation.tailrec
  def m(a: Seq[Long], b: Seq[Long]): Seq[Long] = {
    a match {
      case Nil => b
      case firstA :: moreA => b match {
        case Nil => a
        case firstB :: moreB if (firstB < firstA) => m(moreA, b)
        case firstB :: moreB if (firstB > firstA) => m(a, moreB)
        case firstB :: moreB if (firstB == firstA) => m(moreA, moreB)
        case _ => throw new Exception("Got here: a: " + a + "  b: " + b)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Running this on 2.9.1 final, I get the following output:

```
OK! List(2, 3, 4, 7)
OK! List(2, 3, 4, 7)
OK! List(2, 3, 4, 7)
m(Vector(1, 2, 3, 4, 7), Vector(1, 4, 6, 9)) failed with scala.MatchError: Vector(1, 2, 3, 4, 7) (of class scala.collection.immutable.Vector)
m(Vector(1, 2, 3, 4, 7), Vector(1, 4, 6, 9)) failed with scala.MatchError: Vector(1, 2, 3, 4, 7) (of class scala.collection.immutable.Vector)
```

It runs fine for List-y things, but fails for Vector-y things. Am I missing something? Is this a compiler bug?

The `scalac -print` output for `m` looks like:

```
@scala.annotation.tailrec def m(a: Seq, b: Seq): Seq = {
  <synthetic> val _$this: object vectorMatch = vectorMatch.this;
  _m(_$this,a,b){
    <synthetic> val temp6: Seq = a;
    if (immutable.this.Nil.==(temp6))
      {
        b
      }
    else
      if (temp6.$isInstanceOf[scala.collection.immutable.::]())
        {
          <synthetic> val temp8: scala.collection.immutable.:: = temp6.$asInstanceOf[scala.collection.immutable.::]();
          <synthetic> val temp9: Long = scala.Long.unbox(temp8.hd$1());
          <synthetic> val temp10: List = temp8.tl$1();
          val firstA$1: Long = temp9;
          val moreA: List = temp10;
          {
            <synthetic> val temp1: Seq = b;
            if (immutable.this.Nil.==(temp1))
              {
                a
              }
            else
              if (temp1.$isInstanceOf[scala.collection.immutable.::]())
                {
                  <synthetic> val temp3: scala.collection.immutable.:: = temp1.$asInstanceOf[scala.collection.immutable.::]();
                  <synthetic> val temp4: Long = scala.Long.unbox(temp3.hd$1());
                  <synthetic> val temp5: List = temp3.tl$1();
                  val firstB: Long = temp4;
                  if (vectorMatch.this.gd1$1(firstB, firstA$1))
                    body%11(firstB){
                      _m(vectorMatch.this, moreA, b)
                    }
                  else
                    {
                      val firstB: Long = temp4;
                      val moreB: List = temp5;
                      if (vectorMatch.this.gd2$1(firstB, moreB, firstA$1))
                        body%21(firstB,moreB){
                          _m(vectorMatch.this, a, moreB)
                        }
                      else
                        {
                          val firstB: Long = temp4;
                          val moreB: List = temp5;
                          if (vectorMatch.this.gd3$1(firstB, moreB, firstA$1))
                            body%31(firstB,moreB){
                              _m(vectorMatch.this, moreA, moreB)
                            }
                          else
                            {
                              body%41(){
                                throw new java.lang.Exception("Got here: a: ".+(a).+("  b: ").+(b))
                              }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
              else
                {
                  body%41()
                }
          }

        }
      else
        throw new MatchError(temp6)
  }
};
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can't use `::` for anything other than `List`.  The `Vector` is failing to match because  `::` is a case class that extends `List`, so its `unapply` method does not work for `Vector`.

```
val a :: b = List(1,2,3)    // fine
val a :: b = Vector(1,2,3)  // error
```

But you can define your own extractor that works for all sequences:

```
object +: {
  def unapply[T](s: Seq[T]) =
    s.headOption.map(head => (head, s.tail))
}
```

So you can do:

```
val a +: b = List(1,2,3)   // fine
val a +: b = Vector(1,2,3) // fine
```

Comment: Thanks, @dhg. I read this answer once, then read this (http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/112), and then read your post again.

Comment: As already pointed here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/11503173/1421535) you could also use `Seq` as follows: `case Seq(a, b, rest @ _ *)`.

Answer (score 0):

Followed pattern match works for `List`, `Seq`, `LinearSeq`, `IndexedSeq`, `Vector`.

```
  Vector(1,2) match {
  case a +: as => s"$a + $as"
  case _      => "empty"  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Scala 2.10 `object +:` was introduced at [this commit](https://github.com/scala/scala/commit/b3efb3d493605d1c7e106e5f0a697b52ebb3d97c). Since then, for every `SeqLike`, you can do:

```
@annotation.tailrec
def m(a: Seq[Long], b: Seq[Long]): Seq[Long] = {
  a match {
    case Nil => b
    case firstA +: moreA => b match {
      case Nil => a
      case firstB +: moreB if (firstB < firstA) => m(moreA, b)
      case firstB +: moreB if (firstB > firstA) => m(a, moreB)
      case firstB +: moreB if (firstB == firstA) => m(moreA, moreB)
      case _ => throw new Exception("Got here: a: " + a + "  b: " + b)
    }
  }
}
```

Code run at [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/kzP4Ed77SayXgjQbqVDXNA).