# scala Nil type matchs against arraybuffer

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, null, arraybuffer, unapply

I found a strange working construct in scala:

```
(ArrayBuffer[Int]():Seq[Int]) match {
   case Nil => "whoo"
   case _ => "nayyy"
}
```

which returns

```
"whoo"
```

Apparently this already works partially [for Vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19757215/1287856), but not pattern matching. can someone explain me that? `Nil` [does not have any method named unapply](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.4/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Nil$). How is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With objects, `unapply` is not involved (that would be the case if you had used the hypothetical `case Nil() => ...`). Instead, the equality is checked using the `equals` method.

Equality for collections is defined in terms of their elements. E.g.

```
List(1,2,3) == Vector(1,2,3)  // true!
```

The same happens with `Nil` which equals any empty sequence:

```
Vector() == Nil  // true
collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer() == Nil  // true
```