# Implementing foldLeft on IndexedSeq

Tags: scala

As part of an exercise from [FP in Scala](http://www.manning.com/bjarnason/), I'm working on the implementation of `foldLeft` on an `IndexedSeq`.

I wrote 2 functions:

```
  def foldLeft[A, B](as: IndexedSeq[A])(z: B)(f: (B, A) => B): B = {
    def go(bs: IndexedSeq[A], acc: B): B = {
        if (bs.isEmpty) acc
        else go(bs.tail, f(acc, bs.head))
    }
    go(as, z)
  }
```

And, then the `pattern match` way:

```
  def foldLeftPM[A, B](as: IndexedSeq[A])(z: B)(f: (B, A) => B): B = {
    def go(bs: IndexedSeq[A], acc: B): B = bs match {
        case x +: xs => go(xs, f(acc, x))
        case _ => acc
    }
    go(as, z)
  }
```

**EDIT** Note that I got the `+:` operator from `dhgs`'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10199171/matcherror-when-match-receives-an-indexedseq-but-not-a-linearseq/10199441#10199441). It appears to be a member of `IndexedSeq`'s class or its parent since it's available without defining per the linked post.

Is either way better (from a performance or idiomatic Scala point of view)?

Answer (score 0):

The pattern match is definitely more idiomatic.

For performance, they should be about the same, since they are exactly equivalent.

Though only benchmarking would decide, and that includes a lot of assumptions.