# Looking for an FP ranking implementation which handles ties (i.e. equal values)

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Starting from a sorted sequence of values, my goal is to assign a rank to each value, using identical ranks for equal values (aka ties):

Input: `Vector(1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 5, 6)`

Output: `Vector((0,1), (0,1), (1,3), (1,3), (1,3), (2,5), (3,6))`

A few type aliases for readability:

```
type Rank = Int
type Value = Int
type RankValuePair = (Rank, Value)
```

An imperative implementation using a mutable `rank` variable could look like this:

```
var rank = 0
val ranked1: Vector[RankValuePair] = for ((value, index) <- values.zipWithIndex) yield {
  if ((index > 0) && (values(index - 1) != value)) rank += 1
  (rank, value)
}

// ranked1: Vector((0,1), (0,1), (1,3), (1,3), (1,3), (2,5), (3,6))
```

To hone my FP skills, I was trying to come up with a functional implementation:

```
val ranked2: Vector[RankValuePair] = values.sliding(2).foldLeft((0 , Vector.empty[RankValuePair])) {
  case ((rank: Rank, rankedValues: Vector[RankValuePair]), Vector(currentValue, nextValue)) =>
    val newRank = if (nextValue > currentValue) rank + 1 else rank
    val newRankedValues =  rankedValues :+ (rank, currentValue)
    (newRank, newRankedValues)
}._2

// ranked2: Vector((0,1), (0,1), (1,3), (1,3), (1,3), (2,5))
```

It is less readable, and – more importantly – is missing the last value (due to using `sliding(2)` on an odd number of values).

How could this be fixed and improved?

Comment: Why do you need it to be a vector ? Can it not be a list ?

Comment: It shouldn't matter whether it's a `List` or a `Vector`. I just chose `Vector` in the example because it is a [good default](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928327/when-should-i-choose-vector-in-scala) (index-based access as used in the imperative implementation would be very inefficient with `List`).

Comment: @netzwerg Oh yeah it matters in some cases: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10199441/371804

Comment: @Haspemulator Ah, I see, tx!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This works well for me:

```
// scala
val vs = Vector(1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 5, 6)
val rank = vs.distinct.zipWithIndex.toMap
val result = vs.map(i => (rank(i), i))
```

The same in Java 8 using Javaslang:

```
// java(slang)
Vector<Integer>                  vs = Vector(1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 5, 6);
Function<Integer, Integer>       rank = vs.distinct().zipWithIndex().toMap(t -> t);
Vector<Tuple2<Integer, Integer>> result = vs.map(i -> Tuple(rank.apply(i), i));
```

The output of both variants is

```
Vector((0, 1), (0, 1), (1, 3), (1, 3), (1, 3), (2, 5), (3, 6))
```

*) Disclosure: I'm the creator of [Javaslang](http://javaslang.io)

Answer (score 5):

This is nice and concise but it assumes that your `Value`s don't go negative. (Actually it just assumes that they can never start with -1.)

```
val vs: Vector[Value] = Vector(1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 5, 6)

val rvps: Vector[RankValuePair] =
  vs.scanLeft((-1,-1)){ case ((r,p), v) =>
    if (p == v) (r, v) else (r + 1, v)
  }.tail
```

---

**edit**

Modification that makes no assumptions, as suggested by @Kolmar.

```
vs.scanLeft((0,vs.headOption.getOrElse(0))){ case ((r,p), v) =>
  if (p == v) (r, v) else (r + 1, v)
}.tail
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach with recursion, pattern matching and guards.

The interesting part is where the head and head of the tail (`h` and `ht` respectively) are de-constructed from the list and an `if` checks if they are equal. The logic for each case adjusts the rank and proceeds on the remaining part of the list.

```
def rank(xs: Vector[Value]): List[RankValuePair] = {
  def rankR(xs: List[Value], acc: List[RankValuePair], rank: Rank): List[RankValuePair] = xs match{
    case Nil => acc.reverse
    case h :: Nil => rankR(Nil, (rank, h) :: acc, rank)
    case h :: ht :: t if (h == ht) => rankR(xs.tail, (rank, h) :: acc, rank)
    case h :: ht :: t if (h != ht) => rankR(xs.tail, (rank, h) :: acc, rank + 1)
  }
  rankR(xs.toList, List[RankValuePair](), 0)
}
```

Output:

```
scala> rank(xs)
res14: List[RankValuePair] = List((0,1), (0,1), (1,3), (1,3), (1,3), (2,5), (3,6))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a modification of the solution by @jwvh, that doesn't make any assumptions about the values:

```
val vs = Vector(1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 5, 6)
vs.sliding(2).scanLeft(0, vs.head) {
  case ((rank, _), Seq(a, b)) => (if (a != b) rank + 1 else rank, b)
}.toVector
```

Note, that it would throw if `vs` is empty, so you'd have to use `vs.headOption getOrElse 0`, or check if the input is empty beforehand: `if (vs.isEmpty) Vector.empty else ...`

Comment: Nicely done, but this will throw if `vs` is empty.  Mine won't.  (Trade-offs.  There are always trade-offs.)

Comment: @jwvh It's only the `head` that throws there, and in that case we can actually use any default value, because the result will be an empty `Vector` anyway. (Or just check for an empty `Vector` before)

Comment: Ah, `headOption OrElse`, I should have thought of that. Kudos.

Answer (score 0):

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec

type Rank = Int
// defined type alias Rank
type Value = Int
// defined type alias Value
type RankValuePair = (Rank, Value)
// defined type alias RankValuePair

def rankThem(values: List[Value]): List[RankValuePair] = {

  // Assumes that the "values" are sorted
  @tailrec
  def _rankThem(currentRank: Rank, currentValue: Value, ranked: List[RankValuePair], values: List[Value]): List[RankValuePair] = values match {
    case value :: tail if value == currentValue => _rankThem(currentRank, value, (currentRank, value) +: ranked, tail)
    case value :: tail if value > currentValue => _rankThem(currentRank + 1, value, (currentRank + 1, value) +: ranked, tail)
    case Nil => ranked.reverse
  }

  _rankThem(0, Int.MinValue, List.empty[RankValuePair], values.sorted)
}
// rankThem: rankThem[](val values: List[Value]) => List[RankValuePair]

val valueList = List(1, 1, 3, 3, 5, 6)
// valueList: List[Int] = List(1, 1, 3, 3, 5, 6)

val rankValueList = rankThem(valueList)[RankedValuePair], values: Vector[Value])
// rankValueList: List[RankValuePair] = List((1,1), (1,1), (2,3), (2,3), (3,5), (4,6))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val list = List(1, 1, 3, 3, 5, 6)
val result = list
    .groupBy(identity)
    .mapValues(_.size)
    .toArray
    .sortBy(_._1)
    .zipWithIndex
    .flatMap(tuple => List.fill(tuple._1._2)((tuple._2, tuple._1._1)))
result: Array[(Int, Int)] = Array((0,1), (0,1), (1,3), (1,3), (2,5), (3,6))
```

The idea is using groupBy to find identical elements and find their occurrences and then sort and then flatMap. Time complexity I would say is O(nlogn), groupBy is O(n), sort is O(nlogn), fl